# how to order items for desktop and mobile in bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some problems on the best way to order items correctly for desktop and mobile.

On the desktop mode I want to have (which is currently working):

1. search on the left

   However, for mobile, I want to have:

   - hamburger icon in default position on the left, which currently is
   - search on the right, which currently is
   - brand in the center, but its not centering no matter what I do.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here? I am using flex ordering and margin autos to position the items, but the brand in mobile is refusing to position in the center.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-nav" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
  <div class="d-flex flex-lg-fill">
    <form class="form-inline mr-lg-auto order-sm-last mr-sm-auto">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>

    <a class="navbar-brand ml-lg-auto order-lg-last" href="">Brand</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-nav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: might I suggest to remove brand from the div in which search is written and write it in another div outside

Comment: @lucifer, I am following a design spec.

Comment: you might wanna run the snippet I wrote in answer. It works flawlessly!

Comment: @lucifer, your mobile example does, but now the desktop is wrong. Both need to display like my question states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The below code now works on mobile**

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-nav" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
  <div><a class="navbar-brand ml-lg-auto order-lg-last" href="">Brand</a></div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-lg-fill">
    <form class="form-inline mr-lg-auto order-sm-last mr-sm-auto">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-nav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply I have adjusted the `navbar-brand` using css to visible center. The search form will go down when smaller screen to avoid overlap with the logo. I hope this will work for you. If you need any further assistance drop your comment below.

```css
.navbar-dark .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 659px) {
    .w-full {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-nav" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <form class="form-inline w-full mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>

    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="">Brand</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-nav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, however this is not exactly what I am going for. The brand ends up getting covered by the search, so position absolute really doesnt work for me.

Comment: Lets we try using `row` `column` is that okay ?